# No Access to DOMAINSysVolDOMAINPoliciesGUIDgpt.ini

Tags: windows, group-policy

One of our Users is not able to access one specific group policy folder (\DOMAIN\SysVol\DOMAIN\Policies\GUID\gpt.ini). Other users dont get any error message and can access the gpt.ini-file.

**In the command line we receive this error while running gpupdate /force**.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" Guid="{AEA1B4FA-97D1-45F2-A64C-4D69FFFD92C9}" />
<EventID>1058</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>1</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-12-14T07:07:16.970051600Z" />
<EventRecordID>123303</EventRecordID>
<Correlation ActivityID="{C67B8903-7FBB-470B-B582-A062AE57F693}" />
<Execution ProcessID="1256" ThreadID="27824" />
<Channel>System</Channel>
<Computer>COMPUTERNAME</Computer>
<Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1953827594-2852325736-1325633896-3618" /></System><EventData>
<Data Name="SupportInfo1">4</Data>
<Data Name="SupportInfo2">912</Data>
<Data Name="ProcessingMode">0</Data>
<Data Name="ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds">2172</Data>
<Data Name="ErrorCode">5</Data>
<Data Name="ErrorDescription">Zugriff verweigert </Data>
<Data Name="DCName">DOMAINCONTROLLER</Data>
<Data Name="GPOCNName">cn={106E1B5B-2366-4638-B62A-E650673E57C0},cn=policies,cn=system,DOMAIN</Data>
<Data Name="FilePath">\\DOMAIN\SysVol\DOMAIN\Policies\{106E1B5B-2366-4638-B62A-E650673E57C0}\gpt.ini</Data>
```

The Problem occures on every domain controller. I already tried all the solutions i found on the internet. The DFS-Services and the file replication are running, the networkconnection is obviously working. The permissions of the gpt.ini is looking good.

**Permissions of the gpt.ini which brings up errors**

```
DOMAIN\mapTNoDFS:(ID)(DENY)(special access:)

                                                                                                          READ_CONTROL
                                                                                                          FILE_READ_DATA
                                                                                                          FILE_READ_EA
                                                                                                          FILE_EXECUTE
                                                                                                          FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES

                                                                                        BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F 
                                                                                        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(ID)R 
                                                                                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(ID)F 
                                                                                        DOMAIN\Enterprise Admins:(ID)F 
                                                                                        DOMAIN\Domain Admins:(ID)F 
                                                                                        NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS:(ID)R
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you trieds to remove the DENY flags (completely)?

Comment: @bjoster Yes i tried that too, but the error still persists

Comment: What does 'effective permissions' say?

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't access by UNC Path？
Then make sure that DCs are pointing to itself as a preferred or alternative DNS server, and run ipconfig /flushdns, ipconfig /registerdns, restart netlogon service on each DC.

If you create a new user account for a test，same results？

Have you also follow the article to do a check

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392533%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396